# set the order to a Select menu loaded from channel fields

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a select menu where the values are loaded from a channel field.  Is it possible to set the sort order using Freeform Pro?  The code below does not work and I have not found any documentation.  Surely though there must be a way to sort the contents of a select menu loaded from a channel by something other than entry_id.

```
           {freeform:field:field_001
            attr:id="493"
            attr:class="form-control"
            attr:orderby="title"
            attr:sort="asc"}
```

I also tried this code below but obviously the data would not submit.

```
        <p><label for="field_001">First Choice</label><span class="required">* </span><br />   
            <select name="field_001" class="form-control" id="dd_biology_reu_faculty_001">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}                    
                    <option value="{entry_id}|~|{title}">{title}</option>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            </select> </p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Chalk this one up to "Operator Error!"

This code worked:

```
    <p><label for="field_001">First Choice:</label><span class="required">* </span><br />       
    <select name="field_001" class="form-control" id="field_001">
        <option value="">Select</option>
                {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_field" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}                    
                    <option value="{title}">{title}</option>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            </select> </p>
```

Comment: If this answer isn't the solution, please delete it. I also deleted your other answer post since it's not an answer.